# Unconditionally stable numerical method for 1st order non-linear coupled ODEs?

Tags: computational-physics, stability

I am attempting to numerically solve the following system of ODEs:

$$\begin{gather}\frac{dT_1}{dt} = f_1(T_1,T_2), \quad T_1(t=0)=T_{1,0} \\[3pt]
\frac{dT_2}{dt} = f_2(T_1,T_2), \quad T_2(t=0)=T_{2,0}\end{gather}$$

The functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ have $T$ and $T^4$ terms and therefore are non-linear. I tried the forward Euler method but this becomes unstable even for very small $\Delta t$.

Is there any unconditionally stable method of numerical integration to solve this system?

Comment: Is there a connection to physics?

Comment: An unconditionally stable method for any type of *nonlinear* ODE doesn't exist. On the other hand, forward Euler is about the worst possible method for solving any ODE. Either learn something about numerical methods, or use software like MATLAB or Mathematica.

Comment: @G.Smith Presumably, heat transfer with Newton's law of cooling and radiation?

Comment: @G.Smith: yes, a solid sphere at temperature $T_2(t)$ is enclosed in a hollow sphere at temperature $T_1(t)$. The hollow sphere at $T_2(t)$ is enclosed in another hollow sphere held at room temperature. The solid sphere and former hollow sphere are being cooling down using two separate refrigerators with known cooling capacity. I want to calculate the cooldown profiles $T_1(t)$ and $T_2(t)$. $T$ and $T^4$ arise from conduction and radiation heat transfer.

Comment: Have you tried using something like RK4?

Comment: @Triatticus: that will be my next attempt. But I wanted to understand if there is any unconditionally stable method to solve this system. alephzero perhaps answered my question...

Comment: usually implicit schemes tend to be unconditionally stable but require matrix inversion.

Comment: Mathematics SE or Computational Science SE would be a more suitable place for this question. The question does not ask anything about physics, and physics insight does not appear to be needed to answer it.

Comment: I can't help but be curious about what you are actually simulating. Some layered spheres with extreme temperature dynamics of order $T^4$ with radiative heat transfer?!:-)

Comment: @MPIchael, yes. This is a classical problem in cryogenic system design: how long will a refrigerator (of a known cooling capacity) take to cool down your system. In the OP, T2 is system temperature and T1 is that of a thermal radiation shield around the system.

Comment: I solved this in Python using scipy.integrate.odeint. Solution is stable, no oscillations near zero like what forward Euler produced. Anyone knows which integration method is used by odeint? I'm also trying scipy.integrate.solve_ivp, which enables the use of implicit integration methods.